Query with Import Range
I am trying to select query data from another spreadsheet but it gives me this error "Cannot find range or sheet for imported range."
Here's my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xd02ZCHPuSBNDix3MJ6wUXsiKTme-8pdSwMcW1cZKP0/edit#gid=270316444
And here's the spreadsheet I am trying to reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LMc-wsPvDbjkgzkLuR81IqVqIqOoWZ7bMSUeaRdAqVY/edit#gid=898926167
Based on this syntax: =query(importrange(“URL“,  “stats!A1:C9“), “select Col1, Col2“, 1),
I came up with this formula in Daily Check-In (TEMPLATE):
=query(IMPORTRANGE("1LMc-wsPvDbjkgzkLuR81IqVqIqOoWZ7bMSUeaRdAqVY", "All responses! A2:O"), "select col1, col3, col6, col8, col9, col10, col12, col14", 1)
Can anyone help me find where the error comes from? I also tried referencing another spreadsheet but it's giving the same error.

try to remove the space between ! and A2:O

=query(IMPORTRANGE("1LMc-wsPvDbjkgzkLuR81IqVqIqOoWZ7bMSUeaRdAqVY", "'All responses'!$A$1:$O$22"), "select Col1, Col3, Col6, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col12, Col14", 1)

Please try this as there was an error in the referencing column
Column should be referenced as Col1 and not col1.
I have previously faced this problem during querying.

$A$1:$O$22: This is the correct range

